# How do I write a conditional statement with time

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I’m working on a project that will run at different times of the day. And I want it to do different things at those different times. How to I write a conditional statement based on the time?

For example:

How would I write

```
If time == 8AM:
    do this
Elif time == 10PM:
    do this
```

Comment: If you want to _schedule_ jobs to run at certain times, this isn't the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) is an option:

```
import datetime as dt

# Store the current hour (0-23)
current_hour = dt.datetime.now().hour

# Check if current hour is 8AM or 10PM
if current_hour == 8:
    # Do this at 8 AM
    pass
elif current_hour == 22:
    # Do this at 10 PM (22h)
    pass
```